# How Can I Populate Select Option (Day-Month-Year) from Database in MVC?

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller, dropdown, populate

I am new in ASP.NET MVC. Normally I get the date data in the database like this with input:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control datetime Tarih" name="SozBasTarihi" value="@(Model.SozBasTarihi!=null?Model.SozBasTarihi.Value.ToString("dd.MM.yyy"):"")" />
```

But I want to do this with select option and I want to take the day, month and year separately. I've try something like this but I failed. Can we not use "value" in select option? And how can I do that?

```
<fieldset class="date">
    <label for="day_start">Day</label>
    <select id="day_start" name="SozBasTarihi" value="@(Model.SozBasTarihi!=null?Model.SozBasTarihi.Value.Day.ToString():"")">
        @for (int i = 1; i < 31; i++)
        {
            <option>@i</option>
        }
    </select> -
    <label for="month_start">Month</label>
    <select id="month_start" name="SozBasTarihi" value="@(Model.SozBasTarihi!=null?Model.SozBasTarihi.Value.Month.ToString():"")">
        <option>Ocak</option>
        <option>Şubat</option>
        <option>Mart</option>
        <option>Nisan</option>
        <option>Mayıs</option>
        <option>Haziran</option>
        <option>Temmuz</option>
        <option>Ağustos</option>
        <option>Eylül</option>
        <option>Ekim</option>
        <option>Kasım</option>
        <option>Aralık</option>
    </select> -
    <label for="year_start">Year</label>
    <select id="year_start" name="SozBasTarihi" value="@(Model.SozBasTarihi!=null?Model.SozBasTarihi.Value.Year.ToString():"")">
        @for (int i = 2000; i < 2030; i++)
        {
            <option>@i</option>
        }
    </select>
    <span class="inst">(Day-Month-Year)</span>
</fieldset>
```

I changed my code like this but I still have not found a solution:

```
<fieldset class="date">
<label for="day_start">Day</label>
<select id="day_start" name="SozBasTarihi" value="@(Model.SozBitisTarihi != null ? string.Format("{0:dd}", Model.SozBitisTarihi.Value) : "")">
    @for (int i = 1; i < 31; i++)
    {
        <option>@i</option>
    }
</select> -
<label for="month_start">Month</label>
<select id="month_start" name="SozBasTarihi" value="@(Model.SozBitisTarihi != null ? string.Format("{0:mm}", Model.SozBitisTarihi.Value): "")">
    <option>Ocak</option>
    <option>Şubat</option>
    <option>Mart</option>
    <option>Nisan</option>
    <option>Mayıs</option>
    <option>Haziran</option>
    <option>Temmuz</option>
    <option>Ağustos</option>
    <option>Eylül</option>
    <option>Ekim</option>
    <option>Kasım</option>
    <option>Aralık</option>
</select> -
<label for="year_start">Year</label>
<select id="year_start" name="SozBasTarihi" value="@(Model.SozBitisTarihi != null ? string.Format("{0:yyyy}", Model.SozBitisTarihi.Value): "")">
    @for (int i = 2000; i < 2030; i++)
    {
        <option>@i</option>
    }
</select>
<span class="inst">(Day-Month-Year)</span>
```

Comment: the value attribute goes in the `<option>`s not in the `<select>` Otherwise, when you choose an option, how would the code know what the value of _that specific option_ is? That's true of all HTML forms, not related to MVC. If you want to set the initially chosen option you can use logic to set the "selected" attribute on any given option. But also in ASP.NET MVC you don't need to build your dropdown manually in this way, you can much more quickly use the @Html.Dropdown or @Html.DropdownFor helper functions - plenty of tutorials etc online showing how that works.

Comment: I can not use them because the company I work with does not allow me to use them.

Comment: if they are not allowing you to use them...well firstly why??? That removes like 50% of the benefits of using the ASP.NET MVC framework. What problem do they have with it? The helpers generate perfectly good HTML and save a lot of work, plus automaticaly adding things like validation controls etc if you set it up. Huge time-saver. If your company doesn't like them, they are crazy (IMHO) and just causing you to waste your time creating the HTML by hand when you don't need to. In my company we made our own custom helpers too as utilities to make some custom GUI stuff we re-use all the time.